# Handling the object nullablity check in java

Tags: java, exception

I have the below method in a java class which I am creating the session now my editor is giving me the error that Possible null pointer dereferences in com.config.CassandraConfig.session() due to return value of the called method  for the session I have created and to overcome from that I have to throw a new illegal argument exception, please let me know is it correct way

```
@Bean
    @Override
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() {
    // *** Warning Possible null pointer dereference in com.config.CassandraConfig.session() due to return value of called method ****//
        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        //***  ****//
        session.setCluster(Objects.requireNonNull(cluster().getObject()));

    }
```

and I have fixed in the below fashion

```
   @Bean
    @Override
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() {
        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        if (session == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("session is null inside CassandraSessionFactoryBean method");
        }
        session.setCluster(Objects.requireNonNull(cluster().getObject()));

        }
```

Comment: Note that in Java, `new` will ***never*** return null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```java
    @Override
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws AnyOwnException {
        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        if (session != null) {
            session.setCluster(Objects.requireNonNull(cluster().getObject()));
            //do somthing else
        }

        throw new AnyOwnException("session is null inside CassandraSessionFactoryBean method");
        }
```

you can create your own exception and throw it to handle error in your service.

There is simplier way:

```java
    @Override
    public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() throws Exception {
        CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
        session.setCluster(Objects.requireNonNull(cluster().getObject()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second approach is good because it will throw exception with proper message defined by you.

```
 @Bean
@Override
public CassandraSessionFactoryBean session() {
    CassandraSessionFactoryBean session = new CassandraSessionFactoryBean();
    if (session == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("session is null inside CassandraSessionFactoryBean method");
    }
    session.setCluster(Objects.requireNonNull(cluster().getObject()));
    //do rest of your work
    return session;
}
```

Comment: but sonar is still not recognizing it still giving the same error

Comment: Hi @uffftreee one more thing, you need to return the CassandraSessionFactoryBean object from this method according to your method signature. Please try doing that.